# Recommendation system: ranking multiple logistic regression models

Tags: recommender-system, model-comparison

I have a set of response variables (uptake of product A-C) such as

```
uptake_a uptake_b uptake_c
1        0        1
0        1        0
0        0        0
```

I would like to recommend product A, B or C based on a set of explanatory variables. To achieve this, I was going to build a logistic regression for each one of the response variables and select one with the highest probability

My questions are:

1. Is it reasonable to compare probabilities derived from independent models? Do I need to worry about fixing the baseline?
2. Is there a better way to do this than building independent models? Collaborative filtering comes to mind, but there are too few categories for it and CF won't allow me to effectively exploit the rich set of explanatory variables that I have.

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why a model would  be the basis for recommending a product. Don't you just want a product that is better than others? Wouldn't the uptake rate be all you need?

Comment: Hi, David and thanks for your response. These products aren't directly competing, they belong to different types. Furthermore, it is of interest to sell as many of these different types as possible. What I would like to know is what type of product would interest each user the most based on their observed behaviour. So if we know that your propensity to purchase product A is high, we would recommend it to you and convert it into a sale.